# How can I use PartialEq with circular Rc or Weak?

Tags: rust, weak-references

I have the following struct and when I try to call `assert_eq!()` on an instance of this struct I get a stack overflow due to the circular reference. I tried replacing Rc in the parent with Weak but I get the error: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `Option<std::rc::Weak<std::cell::RefCell<DiskItem>>>`. Is there a way to compare a structure like the one I have?

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Directory {
    parent: Option<Weak<RefCell<DiskItem>>>,
    children: HashMap<String, Rc<RefCell<DiskItem>>>,
}
```

Comment: You should definitely use `Weak` instead of `Rc` to avoid leaks. And you can always implement `PartialEq` on your own instead of deriving it: `impl PartialEq for Directory { fn eq(&self, other: &Directory) -> bool { self.children == other.children }}`. Question though: How does a correct `PartialEq` implementation look? How do you verify that the parent is set to the same object, logically (not by pointer)? (I think you need need a helper function.) (Btw, `Option` is [unnecessary](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Weak.html#method.new) on `Weak`.)

Comment: I think comparing just children is good enough, thank you for that. I can't think of a way of comparing the parent, unless you have a sugestion. You should definetely write an answer so that I can accept it. As for the Weak, I need option so that the root directory can be created with None. Are you suggesting that I create it with Weak::new() instead? Is that better practice?

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães It is more performant, as it saves a branch for each case.